# All js included in one js file not working in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I was looking for a solution to include the theme correctly however the 
"tm-script" js file is including all js file with this code which is not working  with WordPress I tried to search how to fix this. So finally I am asking for an expert advice how to troubleshoot this.

I am not good at js complex task if any one can help me i would be very helpful.

Here is the js file including all js file  at this link

https://shashank-demo-site.000webhostapp.com/wp-content/themes/camp-spillway-retreat/js/tm-scripts.js

I have also included the tm-script file in the wordpress from the function.php file

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'tmscript', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/tm-scripts.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it'll be clear, if you provide the error, why you js not working

Comment: just adding `include('some-file.js')` throwing error, because there isn't function `include()`. you need to look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file

Comment: thanks. Not good with js but will give a try